# How to integrate scalatest with selenium

Tags: scala, selenium, scalatest

From reading http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_selenium I'm trying to intergrate selenium & scalatest selenium DSL.

Here is the code I'm using :

```
class BlogSpec extends FlatSpec with ShouldMatchers with Chrome {


    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\selenium-drivers\\chromedriver.exe"); 
    val host = "http://www.google.com"

    go to (host)
    title should be ("Awesome Blog")

}
```

But I receive this error :

> *** RUN ABORTED ***   java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system
>   property; for more information, see
>   http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest
>   version can be downloaded from
>   http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list   at
>   com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:176)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:118)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:61)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:107) 
>   at org.scalatest.selenium.Chrome$class.$init$(WebBrowser.scala:3756)
>   at BlogSpec.(BlogSpec.scala:12)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) 
>   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
>   ...

The driver does exist at `C:\\selenium-drivers\\chromedriver.exe` Am I setting the driver correctly or is there a separate problem in above code ? Chrome is also not starting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `System.setProperty` in the above code gets called only after Chrome is instantiated, meaning after the above error is thrown.  Maybe you should try setting the system property using `-D`.

Comment: how is a system propery set using -D ? I cannot find any java reference to it ?

Answer (score 0):

I have used Maven for running automatically ScalaTest Selenium integration tests. I didn't have used the ChromeDriver but the HtmlUnit driver. And with Maven you can also set custom properties by the commandline with "-Dxxx".

Check out: https://bitbucket.org/olimination/hello-scalajava/overview for an example Maven webapp project with Scala/Java.

Answer (score 0):

alternatively you can try this instead of extending from Chrome

```
private val chromeDriverPath = "~/Downloads/chromedriver"
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverPath)
import Chrome._
`
```